# Need to pass a value from my tableView to a label on another view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uilabel

My tableView on view 2 has a list of clients. On view 1 I simply want the number of clients to show in int form on a label that shows the total client count.

I thought this had something to do with `numberOfRowsInSection`.

However I am trying all different ways to delegate between the two view controllers and nothing seems to work. I can't get the label on view 1 to increase +1 when a new client is added to the list on view 2.

I have been at it for days and I cannot figure out what I did assumed to be a simple task.

By the way I am quite new at Swift.

**on view 2 I used :**

```
protocol ClientTrackingViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func incrementClients()
}
```

Then I added my: `var delegate: ClientTrackingViewControllerDelegate?`

**On View 1 i used**

`ClientTrackingViewControllerDelegate` in the class line.

I defined the above mentioned `func` like this:

```
func incrementClients() {
    var counter: Int = 0 

    counter = TotalClientsLabel.text 
    if counter == 0 {
        counter ++
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your relationship between your controllers? Navigation controller, modal view, push segue?

Comment: @DejanSkledar it is actually between two tabs

Comment: @DejanSkledar it is actually between 2 tabs

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1) Init variable in AppDelegate.swift

```
var data:Int!=0
```

2) create an AppDelegate instance in your two viewcontroller

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

3) Pass your data by init value on appDelegate variable.

ex:

```
self.appDelegate.data=1
```

Viewcontroller1:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
   your_labelName.text="\(self.appDelegate.data)" // to show label data
}
```

Viewcontroller2:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

var count:Int=0

func incAction()
{
  count++
  self.appDelegate.data=count // pass increment value to first view
}
```

Comment: any more advice? always appreciated

Comment: @MatthewEhrlich, Whether you update increment in appDelegate variable,

Comment: it told me that it cannot assign value because it was immutable, i tried changing all from let to var, it worked and built. but my label did not update at all.